# how KnockOut.js works with Telerik Asp.net MVC extension

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc, knockout-2.0

I'm exploring KnockOut for my current app where I've extensively used telerik asp.net mvc extension library.

I've been exploring KnockOut for couple of days but Now I've just facing a problem how to bind telerik's mvc grid with KnockOut. I dont want to use KnockOut grid api because my app is already using telerik's mvc grid on many different places. So how can knockout data binding works with telerik's mvc grid?

Comment: Take a look at [Telerik grid external databinding](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/grid/externalservicetwitter). There are concepts here that you can explore, like data binding the grid with javascript.

Comment: @Igorrious I'm already using telerik grid in my app at many places databinding is not the issue as such. its the declarative data binding with KnockOutJS that almost seems impossible with telerik grid. I'm saying this after wasting my three days on this very issue but so far I've got no luck. correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I'm just exploring knockout library as well. It seems that telerik has a successor to the mvc extensions called Kendo UI. It utilizes the MVVM pattern. There is a trial version to try out.

Comment: There is a project on GitHub (https://github.com/florianignaz/KnockoutJS-Telerik-MVC-Interfacing) that has "some binding handlers + .NET Extension for providing several common used Telerik MVC Controls with KnockoutJS bindings". It does not have anything for telerik's grid yet, but it may be useful to see how they did it for other controls like the date picker.

Comment: Mike Larned has a post at http://mlarned.com/?p=406 called "Telerik MVC Grid–Dynamic Filters for Ajax Refresh" where he has code that combines telerik's grid with knockoutjs.

Comment: @Daniel thanks for your first link. I have managed to make this grid work in client operation mode but the problem is that it sends server request for sorting functionality. initially I just got rid of sorting. because i don't have much records in grid 20 tops in exceptional scenario may be. but the overall UI is really very complex and there are many grids that are being used on the one UI. so instead I'm using client side sorting with js for that now. not the ideal solution at all but I'm left with no other option. as grid's two binding works in client side mode only, still not fully though

Comment: so Kendo implements its 'own KnockOut' functionality?

Comment: @Simon_Weaver: Yes. You can say that. One would not need to use knockout if it is not already used. Starting from scratch, Kendo has its own "KnockOut" functionality out of the box.
However if you need to use KnockOut then there is a project by Telerik team itself: https://github.com/kendo-labs/knockout-kendo
Also you might want to check http://rniemeyer.github.io/knockout-kendo/